# Documents tab is missing Desktop & Documents Folders

Tags: icloud

I am trying to sync one mac with another, but when in iCloud Drive/ Option/Documents tab - I don't see Desktop & Documents Folders option. 
why?

Comment: What version of macOS are you running? Can you add a screenshot of what’s shown?